# Insert blank lines when using 'tail -f' in cmder

Tags: command-line, conemu, tail, cmder

I recently switched from Cygwin to cmder mostly due to it's awesome interface and all that cool pre-configured stuff. ( http://bliker.github.io/cmder/ )

I am using tail -f very often and when I am monitoring an event I used to hit enter so that I have a few empty lines before my event started or Alt+F8 to clear the screen.

None of those work in cmder, so I'd need a solution or a usable workaround for this.

Comment: cmder is a ConEmu actually.

Comment: umm, so? I don't understand the point you're making (other maybe than forgetting to add a tag)

Comment: The question about ConEmu+cygwin/msys's tail. Not a cmder itself. The point is the same as for "I'm using Windows"... Just a correction

Comment: @Vigh - were you able to get a resolution to this ? Sucks that none of the Windows cmd shells provide this option.

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

ConEmu + git-bash (Install git-Windows first) works fine for this purpose